VLC media player on my Ubuntu 23.10 play videos with a lot of noise to the extend of not getting the sound clearly
I have being using VLC for a while. Now suddenly on my Ubuntu 23.10 when I play a multimedia file there is a lot of noise clutter in the audio. But if I play an audio on RhythmBox it play clearly as is should.
I think this is due to my recent upgrade from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10. I have never have such issues before.
My computer is an HP Envy x360 with a 10th Gen Intel processor and a 12GB RAM.
